# How to embed css in xml?

Tags: html, css, asp.net, xml

I am trying to apply an embedded bar-code font from my css to an xml file. The xml file produces order numbers that I need to display as bar-code.

This document goes directly to email where it then generates a sales' invoice.

This it what generates order numbers:

```
   <font face="barcode">
                <xsl:value-of select="$OrderInfo/OrderNumber" />

              </font>
```

I've tried linking my css using both:

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="App_Themes/Skin_3/style.css" ?>

<link href="App_Themes/Skin_3/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Embedded font in css:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: barcode;
    src: url(Fonts/IDAutomationHC39M_FREE.otf)  format("truetype");
}

barcode
{
    font-family:barcode; 
     font-size: 26px;
    font-weight:normal;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HTML** has a link element to link to external style sheets, but not every `XML`-based format will have such an element. If there is no suitable element, you can still attach external style sheets by means of the xml-stylesheet processing instruction like this:

```
<?xml-stylesheet href="my-style.css"?>
```

... rest of document here...

This processing instruction (PI) must come before the first tag of the document. The `type="text/css"` is not required, but it helps the browser: if it doesn't support `CSS`, it knows it won't have to download this file.

Just as with the link element of `HTML`, there can be multiple xml-stylesheet PIs and they can have attributes to set the type, medium and title.

Example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?> 
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="style.css"?>
```

[Reference](http://www.w3.org/Style/styling-XML.en.html) ...

Comment: `<?xml-stylesheet href="App_Themes/Skin_3/style.css" ?>`

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>`

This is what I have at the very top of my document.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="tutorials.css"?>

Comment: I've changed it and however when I receive the email the order number still has no style. Any ideas?

Comment: The file is very large but so I can't include the entire file. But what happens is that it runs sql code against the data base and passes xml into an email and the email is what I am trying to style with the embedded font from my css. However, I have had some success using in-line styling in the document, but I don't kno how to import a custom font in-line. When I use traditional fonts for example "impact" it does provide some style.